# Is there a way to make a three-dimensional color like buttonface for HTML buttons in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I made a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/240f2vmu/) to illustrate what I mean.

As you can see the one with the default bg color button face looks 3D, is there a way to replicate this with CSS as other colors than the greyish one buttonface is?

```
<body>
    <button>I have buttonface</button>
    <button style="background-color:purple;">I don't have buttonface</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This is web browser specific

Comment: Its because of the shading.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by shading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure you can

HTML

```
<button class="styled">I don't have buttonface</button>
```

CSS

```
.styled {
    background: #00d9f6;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00d9f6 0%, #00a4df 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #00d9f6), color-stop(100%, #00a4df));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00d9f6 0%, #00a4df 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00d9f6 0%, #00a4df 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00d9f6 0%, #00a4df 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00d9f6 0%, #00a4df 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00d9f6', endColorstr='#00a4df', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    border:1px solid #06f;
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 2px #fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:2px
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/z5L7kn15/)

EDIT: for those not aware of this, you can make gradients with [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), that's what I used for the gradients in my code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you mean, but you can try outset borders, e.g.

```
border: 2px outset gray;
```

Instead of gray use the color you want.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/240f2vmu/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "3D"-like effect on the button is due to the use of gradients on the background. Browsers have a default appearance for buttons, and setting the `background-color` as you did will somehow disable/override the default browser styles, that's why the second button looks bad. To achieve a similar "3D"-like effect on buttons with different colors, you can use the gradients in your stylesheets using the `linear-gradient()` function for the `background-image` property:

```
/* vendor prefixes omitted */
/* will make this button have a reddish gradient as its background */
.coloredbutton {
  ...
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #c00, #500);
  ..
}
```

Check this fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arnellebalane/240f2vmu/2/